# Expo push notification not waking up lock screen on android

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

SDK Version: 41.0.1
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

Hi, I’m facing a problem with expo push notification service. Everything works perfectly but a thing, notification doesn’t wake up the lock screen of android devices. It works on ios.

I’m using the snack from documentation, here’s my code :

NotificationProvider.TS

```js
        React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!authContext.authState.isConnected) return;
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => setExpoPushToken(token));
        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
          setNotification(notification);
        });
        responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        });
        return () => {
          Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
          Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
        };
      }, [authContext.authState.isConnected]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('Requêtes', {
      name: 'Requêtes',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
      lockscreenVisibility: Notifications.AndroidNotificationVisibility.PUBLIC,
      enableLights: true,
    });
  }

  return token;
}
```

Doesn’t found any solution on internet. Does anyone having faced the same issue ?

Comment: did you figure out a solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `priority` prop on message object that is being sent through Expo Notifications. It seems like setting `priority: 'high'` solve the problem.

From: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#message-request-format

> `priority` (Android & iOS) `'default' | 'normal' | 'high'`
>
> *The delivery priority of the message. Specify "default" or omit this field to use the default priority on each platform (**"normal" on
> Android and "high" on iOS**).*
>
> *Note on priority: On Android, normal-priority messages **won't open network connections on sleeping devices and their delivery may be
> delayed** to conserve the battery. **High-priority messages are
> delivered immediately** if possible and may wake sleeping devices to
> open network connections, consuming energy.

Answer (score -2):

that is a standard android behavior, to wake up lock screen on notification received, user needs to manually enable this in phone settings

Comment: The problem is : there is no such settings on the phone, and apps like snapchat, insta etc.. Does the thing without enable anything

Comment: @NicolasSerradid you figure out a solution? I am having the same issue.